# how to finish reverting a commit, and how to revert a lot of commits

Tags: git, revert, git-revert

This has to be simple, but I can't find it in `git-scm`.

I've been making a lot of small commits to a public project, and all of my work is bad. I want to remove everything that I've done. Some I've just committed locally, some I've pushed to 'origin master'.

The first commit (a week ago) is `bdbad86`... with the most recent being `e82401b`...

I want to just make all these go away. I've tried to revert one.

```
git status  
# On branch master  
# You are currently reverting commit e82401b.  
#   (all conflicts fixed: run "git revert --continue")  
#   (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)
```

1. **I can't figure out how to finish this reverting.**
2. **I don't want to have to do each commit separately, I want to blow them all away.**

Comment: `git revert --abort` worked for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming here that no one else interjected commits in between your work, and that you bad commits form a continuous range in the repo's history. Otherwise you're going to have to get more complicated. Let's assume your history looks like this:

```
e82401b - (master, HEAD) My most recent private commit
...
bc2da37 - My first private commit
cf3a183 - (origin/master) My most recent bad public commit
...
292acf1 - My first bad public commit
82edb2a - The last good public commit
```

The first thing we want to do is blow away the commits that you haven't made public yet. You can do this with the following command (**note that your changes will be gone and should be considered unrecoverable**):

```
git reset --hard cf3a183
```

Equivalently (and more readable):

```
git reset--hard origin/master
```

Now your view of the repository agrees with the view in `origin/master`. You now want to revert your bad public changes and publish them as a revert commit. These instructions are for creating a single revert commit.

You can use `git revert --no-commit a..b` to revert all the commits starting at the commit *after* `a` (note that!) and ending at, and including, commit `b`. The reversion will be staged for you to commit. So, here, we would do:

```
git revert --no-commit 82edb2a..HEAD
```

Or, equivalently:

```
git revert --no-commit 292acf1^..HEAD
```

Remembering that `HEAD` now points to the same place as `origin/master`.

After running the `revert` command you now have your changes staged and ready to commit, so just run a simple `git commit -m "Reverting those bad changes I accidentally pushed and made public"`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of information I needed. One additional question: how do I get the (master, HEAD) or (origin/master) information so I can tell when to do the two sets of commands?

Comment: @Pat The easiest way is to set up an alternative form of `git log` to get this information at a glance. You can read [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) about the format to use. A good starting base is something like this: `git log --pretty="%h %Cgreen%d%Creset %s %an %Cblue(%cr)"`

Answer (score 9):

Instead of running

`git revert --continue`

Just run

`git commit -m "commit message here"`

If that doesn't work, make sure you've staged all the files involved in the revert. Even the files that you reverted and then discarded changes to.

Comment: I found I was still stuck in the reverting state, even though I had committed everything. I had to run `git commit -m "empty commit to escape revert" --allow-empty`, but that seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This question is already answered correctly, but I just want to address the first point of op's question -- *I can't figure out how to finish this reverting*. if you too were stuck in revert state like me and got here searching for an answer.

it can be straightforward as `git revert --continue`. but only if you're reverting some changes inside a file. if you get stuck in revert state, that's most likely because you're trying to revert a commit that created a file and that file is modified in any of the subsequent commit.

take an example:

```
1c40cd3 added fileB
4e06828 added fileA
faf29dd (origin/main, origin/HEAD, main) Merged in feature5 (pull request #13)
6e735e3 (origin/feature5, feature5) updated file.txt
fb51fca added file.txt
744ba74 Initial commit
```

now, if you're trying to revert `fb51fca (added file.txt)`, it will show you something like:

```
$ git revert fb51fca
CONFLICT (modify/delete): file.txt deleted in parent of fb51fca (added file.txt) and modified in HEAD.  Version HEAD of file.txt left in tree.
error: could not revert fb51fca... added file.txt
hint: After resolving the conflicts, mark them with
hint: "git add/rm <pathspec>", then run
hint: "git revert --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit with "git revert --skip".
hint: To abort and get back to the state before "git revert",
hint: run "git revert --abort".

$ git status
On branch feature6
You are currently reverting commit fb51fca.
  (fix conflicts and run "git revert --continue")
  (use "git revert --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
        deleted by them: file.txt
```

you can clearly see `file.txt deleted in fb51fca (added file.txt) and modified in HEAD.  Version HEAD of file.txt left in tree.`. now, you can do `git add -A` and `git commit ...` BUT

what revert does is goes back in history (in the specified commit), removes the changes that were done in that commit. and makes a new commit. but the issue is, you created a file, now revert is deleting it. in the end, there is no file left to stage and as you know, git doesn't allow empty directories or empty commits.

but there's a workaround for empty commits. as [ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604167/how-to-finish-reverting-a-commit-and-how-to-revert-a-lot-of-commits#comment116812445_61936245) suggested, you can do `git commit -m "empty commit to escape revert" --allow-empty`. git revert probably doesn't use this `--allow-empty` flag and that's probably the reason it can't do a commit gets stuck in revert state.

either way, if you get stuck in the revert state, you're probably doing something wrong. trying to revert something that doesn't make sense.